# XSLT to copy one node value and create a new node

Tags: xslt

Can someone guide me on how to write a XSLT1.0 to create the output as below?
`<csvImportSchema>
    <payload>
        <test>**COPY VALUE**</test>
        <test2>2</test2>
        <test3>3</test3>
        <ean>1111111111</ean>
        <productId/>
    </payload>
</csvImportSchema>`

to

`<csvImportSchema>
    <payload>
        <test>COPY VALUE</test>
        <test2>2</test2>
        <test3>3</test3>
        <ean>1111111111</ean>
        <productId/>
        **<copied>COPY VALUE</copied>**
    </payload>
<csvImportSchema>`

Answer (score 0):

The following XSLT extracts the `COPY VALUE` string between `**` and copies it to the end of the `<payload>` tag. Then the strings before and after the `COPY VALUE` are used as prefixes and postfixes of the `<copied>` tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="payload">
    <xsl:variable name="copyval" select="substring-before(substring-after(test/text(),'**'),'**')" />
    <xsl:variable name="valBefore" select="substring-before(test/text(),$copyval)" />
    <xsl:variable name="valAfter" select="substring-after(test/text(),$copyval)" />
    <xsl:copy>
      <test><xsl:value-of select="$copyval" /></test>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::test)]|@*" />
      <xsl:value-of select="$valBefore" /><copied><xsl:value-of select="$copyval" /></copied><xsl:value-of select="$valAfter" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I don't think those asterisks are really there. And I don't think `node()[local-name() != 'test']` is good practice - I would use `node()[not(self::test)]`. If necessary at all.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: I improved my answer with your suggested better practice. Concerning the asterisks: Yeah, I wondered about that, too. But this was the question asked and I tried to answer it as given. If the author would comment about it, I could easily remove these lines if desired.